# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, build

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             58.9s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Error:

```
[  +11 ms] > Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED
[   +8 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +10 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +2 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
[   +1 ms] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
[        ]    > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
[        ] * Try:
[   +1 ms] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[        ] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[   +1 ms] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[   +1 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 29s
[        ] 84 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 64 up-to-date
[ +702 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 30.5s)
[   +3 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 31,079ms.
[   +4 ms] Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:406:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildAab (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:202:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:152:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +187 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 182ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Please provide full error logs

Comment: have you tried the suggested flags? run with `--stacktrace` and `--info` .. and provide the full log.

Comment: Hey, I am getting the same thing but only on github actions deployment. not on local machine

Answer (score 0):

I had faced that but after I check these it became fixed:
1)make sure to remove <> in key.properties passwords
2) when you run keytool .... comand if the storepasswword is same to keypassword return nothing from (Return if same as keystorepassword):